# How to move sheet within Google Spreadsheeet using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to move a sheet within the spreadsheeet using apps script.
How to do it?

*Best live!*

Comment: @Rubén This question has more relevant and pure title. Isn't it?

Comment: Maybe, but the body is the the most important part of a question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you looked at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#moveActiveSheet%28Integer%29) ?

It does show an example as well :

```
 // This example assumes there are two sheets in the current
 // active spreadsheet: one named "first", and another named "second",
 // and that the current active sheet (first) is in position 1
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("first");

 // This should output 'Current index of sheet: 1'
 Logger.log("Current index of sheet: %s", sheet.getIndex());

 spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(2);

 // This should output 'New index of sheet: 2'
 Logger.log("New index of sheet: %s", sheet.getIndex());
```

Comment: Wow! Only activesheet! OK! Thanks!

Comment: [Sort sheets by alphabetical order](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTbAnQGFSQ0)

Comment: Is it possible without activating sheet?